# Intersection of all Annihilators of all nonzero elements of a simple R-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, modules, ideals

Need complete proof of the following result.

The intersection of all Annihilators of all nonzero elements of a simple $R$-module $M$ is a two sided ideal of $R$.

[Hint. $Ann(M)$ is a two sided ideal of $R$ and $\bigcap_{0_{M}\neq x\in M}Ann(x)=Ann(M)$.]

Comment: Whoever posed you this question has written a really awkward question.  The hint contains the entire answer basically verbatim. The only thing interesting to prove, if it weren't already proven, is that the annihilator of a module is an ideal.  They should have asked just that, if so.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $a \in \bigcap Ann(x)$ iff $ax=0$ for any $x$. We just need to show, that

1. if $a,\ b \in \bigcap Ann(x)$, then $a+b \in \bigcap Ann(x)$ – then for any $x$ we have $(a+b)x=ax+bx=0+0=0$;
2. if $a \in \bigcap Ann(x)$ and $b \in R$, then for any $x$ we have $(ba)x=b(ax)=b \cdot 0 = 0$ and $(ab)x=a(bx)=0$ (as $bx$ is some element of $M$).

Therefore, $\bigcap Ann(x)$ is indeed two-sided ideal.